# How can I connect AWS by using AWS-CLI in Windows Subsystem Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am totaly new for AWS I am trying to use `awscli` by calling below code :

```
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# aws s3 ls
```

[image]

I applied lots of solution for that:

1. I added port 8888 into Inbound/Outbound Rule set in Windows Firewall.
2. I added below code in `hosts` file in Windows.

```
# End of section
192.168.184.241 localhost 8888
```

3. also I set;

[image]

But the result is the same.

```
Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
```

My proxy setup in my computer: (@Tim)

[image]
I checked proxy setup of my computer. There is no proxy. But I am using Windows Subsystem Ubuntu Linux in MobaXterm.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your computer can't connect to AWS because you've set a proxy that isn't working. Remove the proxy. If you need the proxy I suggest you expand on your question about why, show a command that does work such as a curl to an https website. I wonder if there's some kind of certificate issue with the proxy, but there's not enough information in your question to say. Please do some diagnostics and edit your question.

Comment: @Tim Hi Tim;  I checked proxy setup of my computer. There is no proxy. But I am using Windows Subsystem Ubuntu linux in Mobaextrem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine. You finished your all setup but boom there is an issue in your Windows Subsystem Linux(WSL) Because there is a default proxy for some security issues.(look at below pictures)

Don't be panic. You have to remove proxies from yous settings.
Steps:

1. Be sure all proxies :
   root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# env | grep -i proxy
   HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8888
   HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8888
2. Remove Proxy:

root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# export HTTPS_PROXY=
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# export HTTP_PROXY=

3. When you try to connect with AWS via "aws s3 ls"

An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Remove credentials from linux and then open aws security create a new secret keys again. Again add these keys in aws configure again.
#aws #cloud #linux #windows #azure

```
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# env | grep proxy
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~#
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# env | grep -i proxy
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8888
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8888
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# export HTTPS_PROXY=
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# export HTTP_PROXY=
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# env | grep -i proxy
HTTPS_PROXY=
HTTP_PROXY=
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# aws s3 ls

An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# ^C
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAVZJLEICPZPBKSJ7H
aws_secret_access_key = OJbXb7h6i7/g/xpfYdMdgrQ76dL+eTdEgAsKVsXi
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************SJ7H]: AKIAVZJXXXXXXXXXXXXX7LD4I
AWS Secret Access Key [****************VsXi]: mG+u/oP45HGXXXXXXXXXXXXkizUvXjo
Default region name [eu-west-1]: eu-west-1
Default output format [json]:
root@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~# cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
```